# Firebase Custom Authentication: Security of Firebase Secret in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, firebase, jwt, firebase-security

I would like to use [Firebase Custom Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html) in my Angular app. This action is realy simple:

```
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator("<YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET>");
var token = tokenGenerator.createToken({ uid: "uniqueId1", some: "arbitrary", data: "here" });
```

But there is a warning about security of Firebase Secret in the doc page:

> Firebase JWTs should always be generated on a trusted server so that
> the Firebase app secret which is needed to generate them can be kept
> private.

I am wondering how can I keep my Firebase Secret private if everyone can view my JavaScript source code and read the Firebase Secret there? Am I missing something or there is no possibility to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: This secret should be put on a server you trust and calls to fire base should be proxies through it. AWS just released their API gateway product, which would help you in doing this.

Comment: @George Stocker Thanks for the hint. AWS = Amazon Web Services?

Comment: that's correct, here's a link to what I was talking about: https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you quote is to be run on the your nodejs **server**  (hence - server-side javascript).
The server component `FirebaseTokenGenerator` takes care for generating the token and sending it back to the JS client, **after** the client has authenticated to your server, with *whatever* method you want.  That's why it's named **custom** authentication.

Comment: Make sense, thank you. I was about to run my app on static pages webhosting only so I'll try to find another solution but that's definitely not the point of this thread :-)